# Using Command Line Argument with Python on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook

I need to grasp the concept behind these lines of code. It is really confusing to me. I used Jupyter Notebook to run the code but received the error flag:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--coords",
help = "comma separated list of source points")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The error message:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-i IMAGE] [-c COORDS]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\bamidele\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-720c660a-a69a-48d8-9b23-40bf4a604168.json
```

Comment: Where are you running `ipykernel_launcher.py`?

Comment: You should show your command, too. Not just the result.  It looks like you put image file path after an f Instead of lowercase i .

Comment: I used jupyter notebook. Should I write the code on command prompt instead?

Comment: If you know how to use `%run` to run scripts in Jupyter, you can use the notebook just like you would the command line. I was saying you should post the command you used to try to run the code here in your question.